# Multi level ordering in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp

Why don't cakePHP include all my associations into one SQL query? The only way I have been able to do this is using "joins", but I hoped belongsTo and Containable behaviour was enough.

Here is an example:
Post->belongsTo->Category->belongsTo->category_type
(All models are setup correctly and work.

listing posts with pagination in index, I try this:

```
public function index() {   
    $this->paginate = array( 'contain' => array('Category' => array('CategoryType')));
    $this->set('posts', $this->paginate());
}
```

This fetches the array correctly, but it does it in many SQLs like this:

```
SELECT `Post`.`id`, `Post`.`name`, `Post`.`content`, `Post`.`category_id`, `Category`.`id`, `Category`.`name`, `Category`.`category_type_id` FROM `unit_app`.`post` AS `Post` LEFT JOIN `unit_app`.`categories` AS `Category` ON (`Post`.`category_id` = `Category`.`id`) WHERE 1 = 1 LIMIT 20
SELECT `CategoryType`.`id`, `CategoryType`.`name` FROM `unit_app`.`category_types` AS `CategoryType` WHERE `CategoryType`.`id` = 1
SELECT `CategoryType`.`id`, `CategoryType`.`name` FROM `unit_app`.`category_types` AS `CategoryType` WHERE `CategoryType`.`id` = 2
SELECT `CategoryType`.`id`, `CategoryType`.`name` FROM `unit_app`.`category_types` AS `CategoryType` WHERE `CategoryType`.`id` = 2
```

This makes it difficult to order this query on CategoryType.name ASC.
Any suggestions?

If joins are only option, do I have to unbind the models before querying?
Will pagination work fine with joins?

Note! this is just a small part of all models, the resulting post->index need to fetch many other models through similar associations also.

(tested on cake 2.2.0 and v2.4.0-dev, php v5.4.11)

UPDATE! ---------

I just wanted to show my findings. I have now solved this without joins, but I had to re-bind in the model to get it working.

This is basically what I did to get it to work (also with paginations and sorts):
In Post model:
Added a bind function:

```
  $this->unbindModel(array(
    'belongsTo' => array('Category')
  ));

  $this->bindModel(array(
    'hasOne' => array(
      'Category' => array(
        'foreignKey' => false,
        'conditions' => array('Category.id = Post.category_id')
    ),
    'CategoryType' => array(
      'foreignKey' => false,
      'conditions' => array('CategoryType.id = Category.category_type_id')
    ))));
```

Then I added this to my index in Post controller:

```
  $this->Post->bindCategory();
  $this->paginate = array('contain' => array('Category' ,'CategoryType'));
  $this->set('posts', $this->paginate());
```

I include table headers also just for documentation:

```
<th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('CategoryType.name', 'Type'); ?></th>
<th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Category.name', 'Category'); ?></th>
```

I hope this post can help others as well :)

I am also going to test this Behaviour to see if I can omit all the bind-functions as well: https://github.com/siran/linkable/

There are lots of plugins to cake, but cake should have a "certification" of the plugins. It is quite difficult to find the fully working and tested ones on github :)

I also miss a site like railscasts.com just for cake :D

/MartOn

Comment: I agree with you that CakePHP doesn't always generates efficient queries. I'm wondering if other ORM frameworks are better at this, however. In the end, it's good practice (as you did) to analyse the generated SQL statements and (if required) try to optimize them. I specifically mentioned *if required*, because sometimes it really depends on how often a query will be performed and optimization is critical. For *very* complex relations, it is possible to use custom (raw SQL) queries, but only as a last resort.

Comment: A cleaner solution in those situations is to wrap your (complex) queries in a "database view" (`CREATE VIEW post_with_category AS ...` and use that as a database-source for your model. This way your CakePHP model can be kept simple and the database view will act as a 'abstraction layer'. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html IMO try to use CakePHP queries where possible, but don't *force* yourself into using them if things get so complicated that it will only make your code more difficult to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must use JOINs to be able to order based on an associated models results.

Yes, you can paginate with JOINs.  Just pass your options (including JOINs) to your paginate prior to actually calling `$this->paginate();`.  (there are many resources online for how to paginate with JOINs)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.. I really like my controllers as dry as possible, so I need to put this into the Model. I do not understand why Cake does not figure this automagically, but I recon there are several reasons for this :)

Comment: @Mart0n - Np.  Anything/everything query related should be in your model already anyway.  Personally, I'd rather them do the queries as they are, and allow me to join if/when I need to.  I'll often contain 8-10 other models, and doing a JOIN(s) would not be ideal.

Comment: Hi @Dave, not sure what you mean. I know that model-related stuff should stay in models. If I want paginate with sorting to work, joins or re-binding seems to be only option in Cake

Comment: @Mart0n - you shouldn't need to bind/unbind/rebind anything - seems a lot more complicated IMO that just using JOINs.  To each their own though.  Bottom line, you cannot just use associations and contain to return data ordered by a contained model.

Comment: The solution I found here, was found on Mark Story's blog. That is why I whent for this. I have tested it today on a large database and it works great. I now only miss a left join subquery to get it all to work properly.